# Use separate <fontname>.fontspec file with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

When I use fontspec and XeLaTeX, I can put my fonts in a separate `fonts/` subdirectory and place `<fontname>.fontspec` files next to my TeX files to specify how fontspec should find the font (Example 1 below). Using unicode-math I can set the math font with `\setmathfont` if I specify the path, filename and extension inline (Example 2 below). However, with unicode-math it seems I cannot use an external `<fontname>.fontspec` like with fontspec (Example 3 below): In the log I see the `.fontspec` file loaded multiple times, then a `kpathsea` error, and then `fontspec error: "font-not-found"`.

How do I specify the path to a math font specified with unicode-math's `\setmathfont{Foo}` in a separate file, e.g. `Foo.fontspec`?

---

### Example 1: fontspec and external .fontspec file (works)

**example.tex**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

**ArnoPro.fontspec**

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Arno Pro]
{
Path=fonts/,
Extension=.otf,
UprightFont=ArnoPro-Regular,
BoldFont=ArnoPro-Bold,
ItalicFont=ArnoPro-Italic,
BoldItalicFont=ArnoPro-BoldItalic,
}
```

**xelatex example.tex**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2018/04/04 v3.7g configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifetex/ifetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/ifetex/ifetex.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (./ArnoPro.fontspec)
No file example.aux.
[1] (./example.aux) )
Output written on example.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on example.log.
```

---

### Example 2: unicode-math and inline configuration (works)

**example-math-inline.tex**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Path=fonts/,Extension=.ttf]{CambriaMath}
\begin{document}
$Hello world$
\end{document}
```

**xelatex example-math-inline.tex**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example-math-inline.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2018/04/04 v3.7g configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifetex/ifetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/ifetex/ifetex.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-memoir.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
No file example-math-inline.aux.
[1] (./example-math-inline.aux) )
Output written on example-math-inline.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on example-math-inline.log.
```

**example-math-inline.pdf**

[image: "Helloworld" in Cambria Math]

---

### Example 3: unicode-math and external .fontspec file (error; no output)

**example-math-external.tex**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
$Hello world$
\end{document}
```

**CambriaMath.fontspec**

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Cambria Math]
{
Path=fonts/,
UprightFont=CambriaMath.ttf,
}
```

**xelatex example-math-external.tex**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example-math-external.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2018/04/04 v3.7g configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifetex/ifetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/plain/ifetex/ifetex.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-memoir.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
(./CambriaMath.fontspec) (./CambriaMath.fontspec) (./CambriaMath.fontspec)
(./CambriaMath.fontspec) (./CambriaMath.fontspec) (./CambriaMath.fontspec)kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[fonts/Cambria Math.ttf]/OT', contains '['


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Cambria Math" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.3 \setmathfont{Cambria Math}

? 
! Emergency stop.
!...............................................  

l.3 \setmathfont{Cambria Math}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on example-math-external.log.
```

Comment: Hm. Do you really have a CambriaMath.ttf? On my system the math is inside cambria.ttc. Also I don't quite understand what "upright font" should mean in combination with a math font - \setmathfont doesn't setup a *family* like \setmainfont. Side remark: I don't think that ArnoPro-Regular has the necessary math table to work as math font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The example loaded Arno Pro only for the Latin math letters, disabling the script features found only in math fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, the inline math example was incorrect; I was actually testing inline math using CambriaMath.ttf extracted from cambria.ttc using FontForge. I've updated the example code.