# Fontspec on Overleaf has trouble with .fontspec files

Tags: luatex, fontspec, overleaf

I am trying to use a non-standard font ([Figtree](https://github.com/erikdkennedy/figtree)) on Overleaf while keeping the main directory as clean as possible. The directory looks like this:

```
font/
    Figtree-Bold.otf
    Figtree-BoldItalic.otf
    Figtree-Italic.otf
    Figtree-Regular.otf
Figtree.fontspec
main.tex
```

`main.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[quiet, no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon, mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}% set up main math font

\setmainfont{Figtree}
\setmathfont{Figtree-Regular}[range=up/{latin,Latin,num}]
\setmathfont{Figtree-Italic}[range=it/{latin,Latin}]
\setmathfont{Figtree-Bold}[range=bfup/{latin,Latin,num}]
\setmathfont{Figtree-BoldItalic}[range=bfit/{latin,Latin}]

\begin{document}
test $1 + 1 = 2$
\end{document}
```

and `Figree.fontspec` looks like this:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree]{
Path = font/,
Extension = .otf,
UprightFont = *-Regular,
BoldFont = *-Bold,
ItalicFont = *-Italic,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic%
}
```

The Overleaf document is available here: [Overleaf MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zvythctjszhj#818b56)

The document does not compile with `LuaLaTeX`, saying that "Figtree-Regular" is not found. I also tried with `XeLaTeX` but it seems like compilation does not even finish. However, this compiles without issue on my local setup (TeXShop on Mac). I have two questions:

1. Why can't Overleaf find Figtree-Regular?
2. Ideally, the `Figree.fontspec` file would also be in `font/`, but doing this causes the compiler to not find the Figtree font altogether. I presume it's because it cannot find the `.fontspec` file. Is there a way to fix this? **edit:** as mentioned in David's comments, there is no reason to expect this behavior. I only observed this behavior on a local setup where the `.fontspec` file was in a "standard texmf location".

Comment: If the same setup works locally, you may need to contact Overleaf support.

Comment: do you have the font installed system wide locally?  are you sure the fontspec file is read there? does it show in the log?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It turns out that I did have Figtree installed system-wide (I forgot about that while debugging). The real issue is `unicode-math` not reading .fontspec files, which is not really a bug, just a missing feature, and there is already a question about it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437855/use-separate-fontname-fontspec-file-with-unicode-math

Comment: I’ll edit the question accordingly when I get back to my computer, but I guess this question can be closed?

Comment: @IsaacRen `unicode-math` does read `.fontspec` files, they just need to refer to the fontname you are actually loading. Anyway see my answer.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I am mistaken then, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the right fontname if you want the .fontspec file to be respected. `\setmathfont{Figtree-Regular}` will look for `Figtree-Regular.fontspec`, not for `Figtree.fontspec`. Similarly the content of the .fontspec file needs to specify `\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree-Regular]{...}` if you want it to have any effect, `\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree]{...}` only affects loads of `\setmathfont{Figtree}` (or `\setmainfont{Figtree}` etc.), not anything with `Figtree-Regular`.

If you don't want to create so many files you can alternatively put all the `\defaultfontfeatures` commands inside of one `Figtree.fontspec`. This will not be read automatically when you load e.g. `Figtree-Regular`, but as long as you load `Figtree` first it will already be loaded.

E.g. if you put into `Figtree.fontspec`:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree-Bold]{
  Path = font/,
  Extension = .otf,
}
\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree-BoldItalic]{
  Path = font/,
  Extension = .otf,
}
\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree]{
  Path = font/,
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic%
}
\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree-Italic]{
  Path = font/,
  Extension = .otf,
}
\defaultfontfeatures[Figtree-Regular]{
  Path = font/,
  Extension = .otf,
}
```

then your example works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution!